# Name these entities which have deeply puzzled mankind

Tags: riddle, word

We have existed since the dawn of time,
Yet we're not older than a blink of an eye

We may be entities of creation,
or entities of destruction

Behold, however, and you shall see
We're nothing but dust

People used to think we were of some ethereal nature
It has been dismissed, in favour of something somewhat more mature

We can be everywhere,
We can stay nowhere

We can't, however, be torn apart
For which we have no part.

Who are we?

Hint:

> "Behold", "creation" and "destruction" all take their meanings from a very specific context
>
>  The second and third stanzas form an antithesis, representing "two sides of the same coin"

Comment: are you talking about neutrinos ?

Comment: I would like to answer this but i don't have enough smarts to layout the explanation.

Comment: @Ivan Barreto Does the answer include multiple particles? Since it reads entities. Do you mean Bosons and Fermions like smaller than atoms?

Comment: Seems it should be "torn apart" rather than "teared apart"?

Comment: No, maybe and yes. I can't give a category, but taking a look at the answers may help with the clues.

Comment: Why is my question is getting downvoted?

Comment: @IvanBarreto Probably because your riddle could pertain to almost any aspect of quantum physics as indicated by the different answers, all of which are based on this subject.  As it is, it's not quite detailed enough to make out exactly which specific aspect of quantum mechanics you had in mind (I guess particle/wave duality, like @Sabre)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are:

> Photons

We have existed since the dawn of time,
Yet we're not older than a blink of an eye

> as Light (photons) moves at the speed of light, they don't actually experience time.

We may be entities of creation,
or entities of destruction

> Light forms the source of energy that powers light, radiation (which is light) can also breakdown molecules and kill people.

Behold, however, and you shall see
We're nothing but dust

> In air you only see light as reflection off of dust. Also a note on behold, let there be light. <sub>Biblic'n'stuff</sub>

People used to think we were of some ethereal nature
It has been dismissed, in favour of something somewhat more mature

> THe photon is a pretty recent phenomenon, previous to that I am not sure what they believed probably some like blobby thingamajig, but photons are definitely a more refined theory.

We can be everywhere,
We can stay nowhere

> Light moves at the speed of light always, also EM waves (light) is everywhere there is stuff (depending on your thoughts on gravitons it gets crazy)

We can't, however, be teared apart
For which we have no part.

> photons can't be torn apart, as they don't have a mass to tear apart.

Who are we?

> We are photons

Comment: That's very close, but still not the intended solution. You've got half the clues. Did you see my hint? May help you with these.

Comment: I was thinking this too; interestingly on the photon "blobby thingamajig" the answer is actually in the clue "ethereal nature": before photons a popular theory was [luminiferous (a)ether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether). Also I think creation/destruction could refer to constructive/destructive interference.

Comment: Absolutely correct. The "something" that replaced aether theory was simply the birth of special relativity. And the wave nature of light is manifested as constructive and destructive interference. Could you guess what the other clue is all about?

Comment: Yeah by "dust" you mean particle, and in those two clues you're hinting at the particle-wave duality. I would guess that "behold" is referencing the double-slit experiment?

Comment: @Sabre I am thinking you probably could get credit for wave particle duality if you want to run with it.

Comment: @Sabre 2nd stanza is about waves, 3rd is about particles, and the last stanza is saying that particles and waves cannot be separated.  Yeah, that's probably the right answer.

Comment: Notice, however, what the 'which' in the last line refers to: For _which_ we have no part -> We have no part for (us to be torn apart)

Comment: EM waves can be separated in frequency components. Even monochromatic beams of light are made of smaller parts. This indivisibility is essential my answer: Which indivisible entities have most puzzled mankind?

Comment: @IvanBarreto sorry for not continuing my answer, but I am not sure what you are leaning towards, I think more specifically photons(?) could be it, but I am not sure. Gravitons strikes me as a possibility but I like photons better on some clues. I am not practiced in the realms of physics as much as ideal, so what was the answer you were going for?

Comment: Yes, I was asking more specifically for photons (gravitons wouldn't fit the clue about aether theory). But, since I noticed my poem was ambiguous in this respect, your answer is all right too.

Comment: If I was referring to light all along, wouldn't it make more sense to make the entire thing in singular instead?

Comment: Okay thanks, I will update to more accurately reflect your intended answer.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is a

> Star

We have existed since the dawn of time

> Stars have existed since the dawn of time, they are believed to have a part in the creation of our universe

Yet we're not older than a blink of an eye

> Stars are constantly making new atoms inside themselves

We may be entities of creation

> As stated in the first explanation, they are believed to have a part in the creation of our universe

Or entities of destruction

> Stars can turn into black holes when they die or collapse

Behold, however, and you shall see, We are nothing but dust

> Stars are made of *stardust* and so is essentially everything in the universe

People used to think we were of some ethereal nature

> People used to think that stars were holes in the sky and there were gods looking down on them.

It has been dismissed in favour of something somewhat more mature

> We now know stars are big balls of elements and fire.

We can be everywhere

> Everyone in the world sees them at different times

We can stay now where

> They slowly move during the night

We can't, however be teared apart

> You can't tear them apart they explode or "fold in" on themselves

For which we have no part

> Stars are big balls of fused elements and have no actual "parts"

Who are we

> Stars

Answer (score 2):

You are

> Chemical elements or atoms.

We have existed since the dawn of time,

> Hydrogen was the first atom or matter to ever exist in the universe.

Yet we're not older than a blink of an eye

> Atoms are constantly created inside the cores of stars through nuclear fusion, billions of them per second

We may be entities of creation,

> Every kind of life we know is based on Carbon

or entities of destruction

> Hydrogen bomb rings a bell? :(

Behold, however, and you shall see
We're nothing but dust

> Lots of possibilities: "we are all formed by star dust" is my favourite though :)

People used to think we were of some ethereal nature

> First elemental subdivision was fire, earth, water and wind. Then ether came along to explain how EMW propagated through space.

It has been dismissed, in favour of something somewhat more mature

> The ether model was abandoned

We can be everywhere,

> Yes, you are!

We can stay nowhere

> Matter and anti-matter (atoms and anti-atoms) can be created literally from nowhere.

We can't, however, be teared apart

> Atom from greek *ἄτομος* - àtomos -, indivisible

For which we have no part.

> As we all know the atom isn't indeed indivisible, but formed by protons and electrons

Answer (score 1):

Since this has been guessed, but deleted due to a poorly written answer:

> Are you [neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino)?

We have existed since the dawn of time,
Yet we're not older than a blink of an eye

> Neutrinos were produced in the Big Bang with the rest of matter.
>  Neutrinos are created with large Lorentz factors, so one that has been *alive* for years in our rest frame could be alive for under a second in its own.

We may be entities of creation,
or entities of destruction

> Neutrinos are created or destroyed in interactions with other particles. In these interactions, one or more particles are destroyed and others are created.

Behold, however, and you shall see
We're nothing but dust

> They do not interact electromagnetically, so they cannot be *seen* in the traditional sense. They are everywhere but often go unnoticed, so you could call them the dust of elementary particles.

People used to think we were of some ethereal nature
It has been dismissed, in favour of something somewhat more mature

> The neutrino was thought up as a kind of "ghost particle", which carried off some energy never to be detected, i.e. [otherworldly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ethereal)
>  Now we know not only that they exist, but that they interact and [can be detected.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_detector)

We can be everywhere,
We can stay nowhere

> Neutrinos are everywhere. *See [relic neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_neutrino_background)*
>  Neutrinos are always on the move. With mass under an eV, most neutrinos are practically travelling at the speed of light with typical energies.

We can't, however, be teared apart
For which we have no part.

> They are fundamental particles; they cannot be reduced to components.

Comment: Nice work, but neutrinos may last veeeery long in mostly empty intergalactic space since it interacts so weakly with matter. All the other points fit very well.

Comment: Roland, I never posted my answer because it would have been poorly written, thus no answer was deleted. Thanks for laying this out. On the dust reference I was looking at this [Cosmic Microwave Background](http://staff.www.ltu.se/~lassew/AO1/mtf109/mtfxxx-filer/Astro13.pdf) CMB

Comment: @Moonbutt74 One of the first answers, by siewake, was *neutrinos*. Several people, including myself, were thinking neutrinos, but the answer was unexplained and then deleted for that reason. There's a reputation threshold to view deleted answers, and I think it's around 1,000.